# Extract portion of text file from first occurrence of one string to first occurrence of another

Tags: regex, perl, text-editing, mysqldump

How can I extract a portion of a large text file, starting at the first occurrence of FOO and ending at the first occurrence of BAR?

In my case, I'm trying to extract a portion of a sql file created by mysqldump.

Comment: Hope this helps `sed -n '/FOO/,/BAR/ {p; /BAR/q}' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credits to [@dgig](https://superuser.com/users/333809/dgig) and [@Paulo](https://superuser.com/users/597091/paulo) who helped me with their feedback! **Final** `perl` one-liner here:

```
perl -lne 'if(/FOO/../BAR/){s/.*?(FOO)/$1/ if!$i++;s/BAR\K.*//&&print&&exit;print}' file
```

**Explanation:**

```
if(/FOO/../BAR/){        # perform the following actions on each line, starting
                         # with a line that contains FOO, and up to and including
                         # a line that contains BAR  
s/.*?(FOO)/$1/ if!$i++;  # only on the first line that contains FOO,
                         # delete all characters before FOO  
s/BAR\K.*//&&print&&exit;# if the line contains BAR, remove characters
                         # after BAR, print the line and stop processing  
print                    # simply print the line contents
```

---

**Old answer:**

Credits to [@Paulo](https://superuser.com/users/597091/paulo) for a simple `sed` solution. It's just as simple and easy to read in `awk`:

```
awk '/FOO/,/BAR/' file
```

It could be too simple, though: it returns whole lines and not exactly "a portion of text starting at the first occurrence of FOO and ending at the first occurrence of BAR". I believe that to mean that FOO should be the first word, and BAR the last. Doing exactly that requires a more convoluted answer. Let me try to accomplish that in `perl`.

Simple case (returns whole lines):

```
perl -lne 'print if /FOO/../BAR/' file
```

Complex case (exactly from FOO to BAR):

```
perl -lne 'if(/FOO/../BAR/){$_=~s/.*?(FOO)/$1/ if!$i++;$_=~s/BAR\K.*//;print}' file
```

I like this equivalent solution, that assigns a variable to the range operator:

```
perl -lne 'if($a=/FOO/../BAR/){$_=~s/.*?(FOO)/$1/ if$a==1;$_=~s/BAR\K.*// if$a=~/E/;print}' file
```

**Note:** It is assumed that there is only one portion of text to be extracted, i.e. we should not encounter another FOO after the first paragraph delimited by FOO and BAR.

Otherwise, the simple case is already not so simple anymore in `awk`:

```
awk '/FOO/,/BAR/ {print; if ($0~/BAR/) {exit} }' file
```

and in `perl`:

```
perl -lne '(print&&/BAR/&&exit) if /FOO/../BAR/' file
```

And the complex, more refined solutions become:

```
perl -lne 'if(/FOO/../BAR/){$_=~s/.*?(FOO)/$1/ if!$i++;$_=~s/BAR\K.*//&&print&&exit;print}' file
```

and:

```
perl -lne 'if($a=/FOO/../BAR/){$_=~s/.*?(FOO)/$1/ if$a==1;$_=~s/BAR\K.*//&&print&&exit if$a=~/E/;print}' file
```

---

This example shows how a one-liner can go from being exceptionally clear and self-explanatory to what looks like an obscure sequence of random characters, for having added just a little more complexity to the problem. Wherever needed, I would recommend writing a stand alone, maintainable, readable script  where extra features can be easily added and corner cases taken into account.

Comment: Thanks for these answers, unfortunately in my case it doesn't work - it does start the output file at the right point, but then goes all the way through the end of the file without stopping at 'BAR'.

Comment: Update: Tried your solutions on a text from Gutenberg free books - in this case, it worked without issue. In my case though, a large sql file, it did as I described in my first comment. I'm not sure why the difference would occur though.

Comment: @dgid Thanks for the feedback. Could it be case-sensitivty? Special characters? Please post an extract so we can check whether it's a corner-case I didn't think of. It's hard for me to say otherwise.

Comment: @simlev You're right, I didn't think about first occurrence, I thought the line that has the first occurrence. Your interpretation is more close to the OP request. In sed I think could be done, which is a hard work without Perl regex. About the `awk`, I think you have to exit right after printing the line with `BAR`, or awk will print any other block with those words, as `sed` do.

Comment: @Paulo Thanks for the feedback, you're right.

Comment: @dgid Please check if there is a second FOO after the first BAR: as per my ''Note:'' and as correctly pointed out by Paulo this possibility is not taken into consideration in my solutions.

Comment: @simlev hi! Thanks for all of this. Yes, there definitely is a second occurrence of the word so maybe that accounts for this. My file is a mysqldump file, similar to this generic example I found (though about 1G). https://github.com/mrdavidlaing/pressupbox-development-boilerplate/blob/master/tests/wordpress.sample.sql

Comment: @simlev and Paulo - fantastic - the updated perl one liner works great - thanks a lot! A real time saver.

Answer (score 2):

In this case it was not so difficult I thought it could be.
With `sed`, from the first occurrence of FOO to the first occurrence of BAR
(I didn't try, but probably something like second FOO to the second BAR would be more difficult.)

```
sed -nr '/FOO/ {
/FOO/ s/[^F]+FOO/FOO/p
:a
n
/BAR/ s/([^B]+BAR).*/\1/
p
/BAR/ q
ba
}' <<<'line1
> line2 FOO text1 FOO text2
> line3
> line4 BAR text3 BAR text4
> line5'

FOO text1 FOO text2
line3
line4 BAR
```

Comment: Upvoted, even though it doesn't work as expected if there is a F before FOO. Greedy `sed` limitation. I'd like to ask you why you didn't go with the simpler `/BAR/ s/(BAR).*/\1/` for the second substitution.

Comment: @simlev About `/BAR/ s/(BAR).*/\1/` you're right, this is more simple and works. I think I just replicated the substitution from `/FOO/` line, I didn't realize that it wasn't necessary.  About if there is an `F` before `FOO`, you're right too but this time I'm aware ;)  I think in `sed`, to deny a word, one must deny char by char `sed -nr 's/([^F]|F[^O]|FO[^O])+//p' <<<'line2 Foo text FOO text1 FOO text2'`